# String identify containers value and syntax

Tags: vb.net

I'm developing a form in vb.net and need to locate the text of a string I use string contains example:

```
DIM valtxt as string = keys.press()
' logical reference to receiver all keys input isn't valid argument.

if valtxt.contains("backcolor") then    
  me.backcolor = color.red
end if
```

the above code works perfectly when the variable receives the letters and finds the word backcolor the color of the word changes background color perfectly. but now when I try to create a syntax to recognize a text in front of the command example if valtxt.contains ("backcolor") & valtxt. Tostring() then I tried to do this but it says that when 2 true are found it is invalid in visual studio 2015

because the goal would be to know if there is the content or keyword valtxt.cointains ("backcolor") and then read what comes frentre and add to me.backcolor = valtxt.contains I got something well next but still could not get the syntax see:

```
DIM colorsys as color
DIM valtxt as string = keys.press()
'< logical reference to receiver all keys input isn't valid argument
'  all keys press value is add on val txt.

If valtxt.Contains("backcolor") Xor valtxt.Contains(valtxt) Then
  colorsys = Color.FromName(valtxt)
  Me.BackColor = colorsys
End If
```

in the above code I managed to succeed however it changes the background color however when it receives in the variable the color name only red, green, blue and I would like it to receive as command in batch as in the command prompt windows backcolor red or any color when identifying the command le up the front and add the value after backcolor as color for background definition.

Example: Backcolor green

How to read the text following a contains and pegalo as a definition of variable?

Comment: Please read the description of a tag before adding it to a question. If you had done that then you would have seen that there's no justification for applying the Visual Studio tag to this question.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading your question correctly, you want to find out whether a `String` starts with a specific substring and, if it does, get the text that follows. If so:

```vb
If valtxt.StartsWith("backcolor") Then
    Dim colorName = valtxt.Split()(1)

    BackColor = Color.FromName(colorName)
End If
```

`colorName` will be the substring from after the first space to the second space or, if there is only one space, to the end. This code ignores casing and validation but that's a separate question anyway.

EDIT:

Reading a bit beyond the question asked, I suspect that the best way forward would be to split input and determine the command from many first, then call an appropriate method to process the remaining input based on the command, e.g.

```vb
Dim parts = input.Split()
Dim command = parts(0)
Dim argument = parts(1)

Select Case parts.ToLower()
    Case "backcolor":
        SetBackColorByName(argument)
    Case Else
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid command")
End Select
```

You might even consider defining an `Enum` for the commands. I think that that would allow you to parse the input in a case-insensitive manner.

Comment: @jmclihinney thank you brother it is all i need to create my program tank's i can use this to identify arguments be ? exemple : bgcolor "green" - h